# Массив данных в базу данных php

Tags: php, redbeanphp

у меня есть массив.

```
$array = [
0 => [
    'name' => 'League',
    'price' => 2321
],
1 => [
    'name' => 'test2',
    'price' => 41
],
2 => [
    'name' => 'test3',
    'price' => 321
],
3 => [
    'name' => 'test4',
    'price' => 124
],
4 => [
    'name' => 'gdf',
    'price' => 321312
],
5 => [
    'name' => 'fsdfs',
    'price' => 1
]];
```

Мне нужно одним запросом отправить все эти данные в базу данных(использую библиотеку RedBeanPHP), можно просто через sql

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю только такой вариант:

```
$beans = R::dispense('test', count($array));

for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    $beans[$i]->name = $array[$i]['name'];
    $beans[$i]->price = $array[$i]['price'];
}

R::storeAll($beans);
```

ps. У меня таблица `test` поменяйте на свою.